# Adding a custom page template to a plugin generated page

Tags: plugins, templates

I have a page template, which is fully working throughout the website other than the pages where the plugin has generated a page such as a job description page, as the plugin that I am using is WP Job Manager. I have tried to include the php file in the functions of the theme and also the template of the theme however, nothing appears and if it does then the content of the template appears above the navigation bar?

Is there anyway in which I am able to get this into this page and any other page that is dynamically created via the plugin, as there will be many pages.

The plugin creates a Custom Post Type which is what is used to create the pages, the pages are not actually existing in the back end.

The plugin is located in the wp-content/wp-job-manager/... and the page template is located in the wp-content/themes/test-theme/universal-template.php

The code I have tried is `<?php include('/wp-content/themes/test-theme/universal-template.php'); ?>` I know this isn't the best way to include a file but I was doing this till I can get it working

Comment: Can you please put more effort in the question and give us code, files, etc that help us see your problem/question more clear and provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: I think we'd need a lot more information to attempt an answer to this.  Does the plugin actually make Pages, or does it create Posts of a particular custom post type?  Can we see any code you have tried?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: Can you paste the contents of template please?

Comment: The contents of the template is just HTML to sit at the top of the page above everything else

Comment: That's what I tried before but none of the HTML is echoing, and if it does. It's above it, is there anyway that within a plugin you can change the page template it is reading

Comment: WP allow you to change/filter the page template. See this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template

Answer (score 0):

You can set the page template by calling `update_post_meta()` with a key of `‘_wp_page_template’`.

Or while inserting posts, you can pass `page_template` to `wp_insert_post()`.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#more-information

Answer (score 0):

Using wp_insert_post() you can add a new post and use an existing theme.

```
  $new_page_id = array(
        'post_title'     => 'examplePage',
        'post_type'      => 'custom_post',
        'post_name'      => 'examplePage',
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_author'    => get_user_by( 'id', 1 )->user_id,
        'menu_order'     => 0,
        // Assign page template
        'page_template'  => "/wp-content/themes/test-theme/universal-template.php"


    ); 
    wp_insert_post($new_page_id);
```